# rbenv fails to install ruby version 1.9.3-p194

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I'm trying to install ruby 1.9.3-p194 on rbenv and the build is failing.

```
$ rbenv install 1.9.3-p194
ruby-build: use openssl from homebrew
ruby-build: use libyaml from homebrew
Downloading ruby-1.9.3-p194.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p194.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-1.9.3-p194...

WARNING: ruby-1.9.3-p194 is past its end of life and is now 
unsupported.
It no longer receives bug fixes or critical security updates.

ruby-build: use readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.12.5 using ruby-build 20170726)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at 
/var/folders/5v/fzhvsdcd4qz2dh3jrhq_y1z40000gn/T/ruby-
build.20170727150432.56530
Results logged to 
/var/folders/5v/fzhvsdcd4qz2dh3jrhq_y1z40000gn/T/ruby-
build.20170727150432.56530.log

Last 10 log lines:
compiling regerror.c
compiling regexec.c
compiling regparse.c
regparse.c:582:15: error: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 
'st_index_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Werror,-Wshorten-64-to-32]
return t->num_entries;
~~~~~~ ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [regparse.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
13 warnings generated.
```

I've been trying to find a solution to this problem and have not had any luck. I appreciate any advice.

Comment: Can you post the content of the log file (`/var/folders/5v/fzhvsdcd4qz2dh3jrhq_y1z40000gn/T/ruby-
build.20170727150432.56530.log`)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Lucas but I was able to figure it out.

Running the following in my terminal got it to install:
    RUBY_CFLAGS="-Wno-error=shorten-64-to-32" rbenv install 1.9.3-p194